# Most popular open-source, free, well-documented game engine for research application

Tags: 3d, physics, quake2

My company is getting ready to propose a stroke and brain-injury rehabilitation tool and we need to know what free, open-source, and well-documented game engine are out there.

- We will be constructing a 3D environment.
- We will need to have good control over characters fine motions (for instance even finger motions).
- We need a good physics engine including collision detection and inverse kinematics if possible.
- It would be very useful if there are already some hooks in the code for providing haptic feedback, but that's not necessary.
- Graphics do not need to be phenomenal.
- It must be *relatively* easy to throw together a proof of concept.

I'm predisposed toward Jake2 because Java's dead easy to program in, but I need more options to consider from you folks who have experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider looking at [ioquake3](http://ioquake3.org/) which is an opensource port of Quake 3. Also, I would like to point out the excellent Delta3d which is a DoD funded and developed opensource simulation engine.

Notre Dame evaluates several engines in the paper [A Survey of  Collaborative Virtual Environment Technologies](http://www.cse.nd.edu/Reports/2008/TR-2008-11.pdf). I would think that this would be best starting point as you will be able to access alot of existing knowledge on engines when applied to virtual environments.

Comment: Just an update - the finished paper can be found at the home page of The International Journal of Virtual Reality: http://www.ijvr.org/issues/issue1-2009/7.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Consider [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/).

**Update:** It's a very solid and powerful game engine, but something funky is going on on their website, I can't open most of the pages.  Don't judge based on that.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth looking at [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/), especially if you already have existing Java experience / investments.

I was pretty impressed by how easy it was to get a 3D environment up and running.

There is also supposedly good jBullet physics integration - although I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/).  It is free and open-source and has the ability to run on multiple platforms using your choice of graphics API (DirectX, OpenGL, etc.).  It's written in C++ and has excellent documentation, in addition to an active community.  Although it doesn't have a built in physics engine, it's relatively easy to tie in any external engine like Havok, Bullet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider between

- Ogre3d,
- Irrlicht,
- Panda3d,
- Torque3d

I think Delta3d is the best.

Their code easy to learn and it applying many rules of C++ Design. I finished read Scott Meyers Effective C++, More Effective C++, and I really like the way Delta3d code implemented.

The Cons: Delta3d community is small, but it really is best open source game engine.